# How to interprete "machen ein bisschen Luft spüre"

Tags: verb

I have been studying German in my spare time for 10 months, so I still have many things to learn. In a grammar book, I have seen a sentence from an excerpt:

> ..., laufe zum Fenster, mache ich ein bisschen frische Luft spüre, und bin hellwach.

How shoud I directly translate the middle part in English? I found 'spüren' is to 'feel, or sense (vt.)'. What's the subject word of the verb 'spüren' here? Is it *ich* or *Luft*?

ADD : it turns out as Björn Friedrich answered, the book has omitted a substantial part of a sentence there. That's why I asked about this strange sentence and I'm relieved what I leared and understood is correct.
[image]

Comment: Context is useful i most cases. You should at least provide the complete sentence you are dealing with. And the part you provided seems to  miss a word at least.

Comment: "mache ich ein bisschen frische Luft spüre" is no correct german

Comment: _is no correct german_ is no correct english

Comment: @Clijsters *no correct english* is no correct topic here.

Comment: _is no correct topic_ - touché.

Comment: Are you sure you got the quote right? If it was *"..., laufe zum Fenster, mache die Verdunklung weg, schnüffle so lange an dem Spalt, bis ich ein bisschen frische Luft spüre, und bin hellwach"*, it would definitely be from "Tagebuch der Anne Frank" and make a lot more sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it arose from a unique transcription error and thus is not related to the German language.

Comment: ... or perhaps an obscure, abbreviated version of Anne Frank's diary?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann obscurely abbreviated as in "just cross out random words"?

Comment: @Tofro   Well, there are various ways to abbreviate a book.

Comment: @tofro oh, I see. the book I have must have shown a wrong sentence. I checked it on the web it's from 'Tagebuch der Anne Frank' as you said. Ich bin erleichtert, was ich gelernt habe, ist richtig! And thanks to all other commeners.

Comment: There is another error in that short paragraph: *Leben-**s**-künstlerin* is a noun, hence supposed to be capitalized. Sloppiness never pays out. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a serious error in your book, because a whole segment of the sentence is missing. The original sentence is from the [Tagebuch der Anne Frank](https://books.google.de/books?id=yM5qAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT169&lpg=PT169&dq=laufe%20zum%20Fenster,%20mache%20ich%20ein%20bisschen%20frische%20Luft&source=bl&ots=5AFm8gY_3o&sig=C2M-GAvO8ekS86vQ-F7ixYGz5Rc&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiamduUjuvWAhVLIMAKHaybAmUQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=laufe%20zum%20Fenster%2C%20mache%20ich%20ein%20bisschen%20frische%20Luft&f=false):

> [Ich] laufe zum Fenster, mache **die Verdunklung weg, schnüffle solange an dem Spalt, bis** ich ein bisschen frische Luft spüre, und bin hellwach.

Answer (score 1):

There are two verbs in that side clause: "*machen*" and "*spüren*". 
"*Frische Luft machen*" is literally "making fresh air" but figuratively means "opening the window and letting fresh air in". To me "spüren" would belong after the colon.

So grammatically correct would be: 
". . ., laufe zum Fenster, mache ich ein bisschen frische Luft, spüre, und bin hellwach."
In this case the structure is like this: `Ich verb1, verb2, verb3 und verb4.` So "ich" is doing all the actions and is therefore the only subject in the sentence.

Comment: exactly, a comma is just missing

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, the above german sentence is not correct german. So either you mistyped something, or the book you are using is not one of the best. Even the sentence constructed by Higgs_Bosons is not quite correct german, as the verb "spüre" still needs an object - what are you feeling/sensing? (In regards to your question, the only thing making sense would be to sense the fresh air...).

But still, to "make" something in german is considered bad german in most cases - teachers like to point that out with the sentence "Sei kein Täter - sei kein Macher" - loosely translated to "be no maker, be no doer" with a pun on the the word "Täter" also meaning "offender" in german (and a "Macher" being a hands-on person), since to make and to do are (mainly) auxiliary verbs in german.

So the - in my eyes - correct sentence would have to be something like "..laufe (ich) zum Fenster, öffne es (das Fenster), spüre die frische Luft und bin hellwach."

Comment: The remarks about "machen" are principally right, but in this case ("frische Luft machen") it is a common idiom (okay, perhaps a liiiiitle bit old-fashioned) for "let some air in".